# gRPC-Core issue in Xcode - Value conversion issue - Implicit conversion loses integer precision

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, react-native

My code works perfectly fine. I have installed the Firebase Auth Package and it doesn't give me any errors. But as soon I add the FireStore Package then I start having this warning again and again.[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5LBo.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In Xcode : File -> Packages -> Update to Latest Package Versions. This solved the problem for me, they released a fix for that bug thank god.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug will be fixed in next release https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/9790